# ExpressJS + SSL self-signed + HTTPS

Tags: node.js, express, https

The first thing is I'm not receiving any error and my website is working, apparently, well.

I just built a webapp using ReactJS and I serve it using ExpressJS. I decided to start using HTTPS and set the server in that way:

```js
let fs = require('fs');
let express = require('express')
let http = require('http')
let https = require('https')
let config = require('config')
let server = express()

let privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./config/key.pem', 'utf8')
let certificate = fs.readFileSync('./config/cert.pem', 'utf8')
let credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate, passphrase: config.sslPhrase }

let httpServer = http.createServer(server)
let httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, server)

//Some routes...

httpServer.listen(80)
httpsServer.listen(443)
```

My server is running as I expect, with just one exception:

[image]

What I was expecting is:

[image]

I dont have any confidential data in my site neither cookies, there isn't any field of type password.

There are lots of tutorial explaining how to implement HTTPS on your site, but even in those tutorials they are showing the same result. It is not what I was expecting.

So part of my question is: **Why is it happening?** 
The second part is: **What should I do?**

Comment: Are you asking why your are getting an untrusted certificate error when using a self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it happenning?

Because your certificate is self signed and thus is not automatically trusted by the browser.  Your communication is likely secure, but the browser does not know if it can trust that the connection is coming from the actual domain that it says it is because it doesn't trust your certificate authority.

> What should I do?

To solve it for all browsers, you have to get a certificate from a service that issues certificates trusted by one of the certficate authorities for which trust is built into the browser.  One free option for doing this is [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/about/).  To solve it for just your own browser, you can tell your browser to trust your self-signed certificate.

You can't get a self-signed certificate to be trusted by all browsers.  The certificate trust system just doesn't work that way.

Comment: I think mentioning [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) here would be useful for "What should I do?".

Comment: @mscdex - I added a reference to Lets Encrypt.